# How to edit binary file after get values from GDB

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdb

I use GDB and want to modify an iOS app. (for example: change score in a game)

So, I set breakpoint, for example:

```
b *0x0032c870
```

and that in the breakpoint, I enter

```
info r
```

after this, gdb shows

```
r0             0x92717c0    153556928
r1             0x7d47a0 8210336
r2             0x0  0
```

And now I know what I need is change r2 to 1

```
set $r2=1
```

Now the value changes in the game.

OK, there's a question, how can I edit in hexeditor to set r2=1 instead using gdb everytime?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I edit in hexeditor to set r2=1 instead using gdb everytime

You *can't*: the value of `r2` is the value of the *register*; it doesn't exist until the program is running.

What you need to do is figure out where that value was *loaded* into the register, and change the code *there* to make it load `1` instead of `0`.

This could be very easy, or tricky depending on how that value is loaded: easy if it's loaded as a constant (just change the instruction to load a different constant). But chances are it's loaded as a return value from some function, in which case you'll have to change that function to return a different value.